# Mixing by and .SDcols in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to mix `by` and `.SDcols` in `data.table` `cran 1.9.6` (and also tested on dev from github, so it is likely a misundertanding on my part)

```
f = function(x){                                   
    print(x);                                      
    res=data.table(X=x,Y=x*x);                     
    return(res)                                    
}                                                  
DT = data.table(x=1:4, y=rep(c('a','b'),2))        
DT[,c('A','B'):=lapply(.SD,FUN=f),.SDcols='x',by=y]
```

I get:

```
[1] 1 3
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c("A", "B"), lapply(.SD, FUN = f)),  : 
  All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

I would expect

```
   x y A B
1: 1 a 1 1
2: 2 b 2 4
3: 3 a 3 9
4: 4 b 4 16
```

I would have expected the by operation to take place and SDcols to be replace by 'x' Could someone explain why I am wrong here ?

Comment: You are giving it a `list(list(x,y))` not `list(x,y)`. That's what you get from `lapply`. So `DT[,f(.SD[[1]]),.SDcols='x',by=y]` works. Fyi, it is recommended to use lists instead of data.tables inside j: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts#4-dont-coerce-j-to-list-use-list-directly

Comment: @Frank, I tried with lists, but that was the same problem (1 nesting to many), your [[1]] is in the wrong position but I get it. Thank you, I keep having problems with that kind of things. Do you want to answer ? `DT[,c('Q','W'):=mapply(FUN=f, mget('x'), SIMPLIFY=TRUE),by=y][]
` would also work I realized

Comment: You can self-answer with what worked for you. I don't really follow how the [[1]] is in the wrong place. `mapply` with SIMPLIFY=TRUE tries tries to create a matrix, I think... not sure that makes sense for a data.table column. Anyway, I'd be curious what you ended up using.

Comment: simply use `sapply` instead of `lapply`

Comment: @eddy: yes, -> Frank I'll write the answer

Comment: or `rbindlist(lapply(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the following works, as @Frank pinpointed, the problem was in the level nesting of the list by lapply

```
DT[,f(.SD[[1]]),.SDcols='x',by=y]
   y X  Y
1: a 1  1
2: a 3  9
3: b 2  4
4: b 4 16

DT[,lapply(.SD, f)[[1]],.SDcols='x',by=y]
   y X  Y
1: a 1  1
2: a 3  9
3: b 2  4
4: b 4 16

DT[,rbindlist(lapply(.SD, f)),.SDcols='x',by=y]
   y X  Y
1: a 1  1
2: a 3  9
3: b 2  4
4: b 4 16

DT[,sapply(.SD, f),.SDcols='x',by=y]

   y V1 V2
1: a  1  1
2: a  3  9
3: b  2  4
4: b  4 16

DT[,mapply(FUN=f, mget('x')),by=y]
   y V1 V2
1: a  1  1
2: a  3  9
3: b  2  4
4: b  4 16
```

Comment: Also `DT[, do.call(f, .SD),.SDcols='x',by=y]`

Comment: What if there is another column `z = c(5,6,8,10)` in `DT`, and one wants to do something like: `DT[,('A','B'):=sapply(.SD, mean),.SDcols=c('x','z'),by=y]`. I had tried solutions in the answer, did not work in such case.